# Phaser 2.6.2 Why objects do not block each other when changing position X and Y?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

The problem is simple - objects do not block each other when trying to crash. Whatever I do, the objects ignore each other and pass each other through.
I also noticed that if you change the position X & Y through velocity, then the objects begin to block each other. But this does not suit me, because the velocity increases gradually, and I need the tank to move at linear speed. And you also need to avoid a rebound in a collision. That is, I need the tanks to just stop moving when they crash.

I posted a working example 
Click [here](https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/vYBgpgg?editors=0010)

```
const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

    let player;
    let cursors;
    let fireButton;
    let weapon;
    let  weapon2;
    let controls;

    let enemy;


    function preload() {
      game.load.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; 
        game.load.image('player', 'https://steemitimages.com/640x0/https://res.cloudinary.com/hpiynhbhq/image/upload/v1516330590/dln77v8bxlbzkrevng0x.png');
        game.load.image('bullet', 'https://examples.phaser.io/assets/sprites/bullet.png');
    }

    function create() {
        game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

        player = game.add.sprite(500, 300, 'player');
        player.scale.setTo(.1, .1);
        player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        player.angle = 270;
        player.enableBody = true;



        cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);

        weapon = game.add.weapon(1, 'bullet');
        weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;
        weapon.bulletAngleOffset = 90;
        weapon.bulletSpeed = 400;
        weapon.trackSprite(player, 0, 0, false);
        weapon.fireAngle = player.angle + 90;

        enemy = game.add.sprite(100, 100, 'player');
        enemy.scale.setTo(.1, .1);
        enemy.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        enemy.angle = 270;
        enemy.enableBody = true;

        weapon2 = game.add.weapon(1, 'bullet');
        weapon2.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;
        weapon2.bulletAngleOffset = 90;
        weapon2.bulletSpeed = 1400;
        weapon2.trackSprite(enemy, 0, 0, false);
        weapon2.fireAngle = enemy.angle + 90;



        controls = {
            right : this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.D),
            left : this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.A),
            up : this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.W),
            down : this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.S),
            fire : this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.Q),
        };


        game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(enemy);
        player.body.immovable = true;
        enemy.body.immovable = true;
    }

    function killThem(enemy,  bullet) {
        console.dir(weapon);
        enemy.kill();
        bullet.kill();

    }

    function update() {
        game.physics.arcade.collide(weapon.bullets, enemy, killThem);
        game.physics.arcade.collide(weapon2.bullets, player, killThem);


        if (cursors.up.isDown) {
            player.y -= 4;
            player.angle = 180;
            weapon.fireAngle = 270;
        } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
            player.y += 4;
            player.angle = 0;
            weapon.fireAngle = 90;
        } else if (cursors.left.isDown) {
            player.x -= 4;
            player.angle = 90;
            weapon.fireAngle = 180;
        } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
            player.x += 4;
            player.angle = 270;
            weapon.fireAngle = 360;
        }

        if (fireButton.isDown) {
            weapon.fire()
        }


        if (controls.up.isDown) {
            enemy.y -= 4;
            enemy.angle = 180;
            weapon2.fireAngle = 270;
        } else if (controls.down.isDown) {
            enemy.y += 4;
            enemy.angle = 0;
            weapon2.fireAngle = 90;
        } else if (controls.left.isDown) {
            enemy.x -= 4;
            enemy.angle = 90;
            weapon2.fireAngle = 180;
        } else if (controls.right.isDown) {
            enemy.x += 4;
            enemy.angle = 270;
            weapon2.fireAngle = 360;
        }


        if (controls.fire.isDown) {
            weapon2.fire()
        }
    }


    function render() {
        weapon.debug()
    }
```

Comment: I haven't understood your comment in the last question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57622217/2107253 sorry ok now I understand what you mean, so actually we have two approaches one with the velocity https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/6uq2fmt1 and the other one without velocity that doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/jo49a8kb that looks like the one you shared on codepen. Please give me some time to give you an explanation in the final answer.

Comment: @nazimboudeffa thank you so much, my friend! I am a beginner in phaser and still have not solved the problem.

Comment: Thank YOU for asking @Rafel you have to know that I am still learning everyday and that you can consider me as a noob too ;) it's why I try to make my examples as simpler as possible also to let other coders to easly understand the underlying, so for this question it's true that I haven't yet found a complete answer on the internet

Comment: @nazimboudeffa I apologize for the long absence. I solved the problem literally in 10 minutes, when I found the time to return to the task :) https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/vYBgpgg?editors=0010

Comment: No problem am also here when I have time :), nice to see your game working